# How can I add a background circle to a sunburst plot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

How do I add a background circle to a sunburst plot in d3? I'm using the standard [zoomable sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373) example:

[image]

I just want a full circle of specified color, to highlight the 'jaggy-ness' of a particular display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is append a circle to the SVG as the first thing after creating it:

```
svg.append("circle").attr("r", radius).style("fill", "pink");
```

Complete example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/9386992).